# Django-oscar error - django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: staticfiles

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, django-oscar

I am trying to start Django-oscar and have followed the instructions as given [here](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/internals/getting_started.html), but when I Try to use `python manage.py runserver` or `python manage.py migrate` I am getting the following error. I don't understand what this is, as I am new to Python and Django. Could someone give a solution to this?
I am using Ubuntu, Python 2.7 and Django 1.8.

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0xb681072c>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 107, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 252, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
    "duplicates: %s" % app_config.label)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: staticfiles
```

Here is my `settings.py` file

```
"""
Django settings for frobshop project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
import sys
# print sys.path
from oscar import get_core_apps, OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR
from oscar.defaults import *

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '1=3_c^!p&9of!*qrq4-muru%n2v_!+n*7ys3j8%ilrcypv%uvw'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',

    #Oscar specific
    'compressor',
    'widget_tweaks',
] + get_core_apps()

SITE_ID = 1


MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

    #Oscar specific
    'oscar.apps.basket.middleware.BasketMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'frobshop.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
            #Oscar specific
            # OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                #Oscar specific
                'oscar.apps.search.context_processors.search_form',
                'oscar.apps.promotions.context_processors.promotions',
                'oscar.apps.checkout.context_processors.checkout',
                'oscar.apps.customer.notifications.context_processors.notifications',
                'oscar.core.context_processors.metadata',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'frobshop.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
    }
}


#Oscar specific - To allow customers to sign in using an email address rather than a username.
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'oscar.apps.customer.auth_backends.EmailBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr',
        'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
    },
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

[UPDATE]
As he instructed, I removed the duplicate App, but, Now, I have the following error when I use `migrate`

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/utils/__init__.py:12: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.utils.importlib will be removed in Django 1.9.
  from django.utils import importlib

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py:78: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class django.contrib.sites.models.Site doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django 1.9.
  class Site(models.Model):

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 328, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compressor/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from compressor.conf import CompressorConf  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compressor/conf.py", line 9, in <module>
    class CompressorConf(AppConf):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/appconf/base.py", line 75, in __new__
    new_class._configure()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/appconf/base.py", line 104, in _configure
    value = callback(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compressor/conf.py", line 91, in configure_root
    'STATIC_ROOT, please define either')
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: COMPRESS_ROOT defaults to STATIC_ROOT, please define either
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
>   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
>   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
```

Your `INSTALLED_APPS` contains `django.contrib.staticfiles` twice. You should remove the duplicate.

Comment: Please check the update, your solution soved the said problem, but now I have a new one. Can u see what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, then I changed my settings.py like this:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`enter code here`

#MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/myshop/media'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [

    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/'),

    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/media/'),

]

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/myshop/staticfiles'
```

it worked.

By the way, I'm using python3.5 and  Django 2.0.9 and oscar 1.5 and mysql 5.7.